# Python Bisection methodd

Tags: python

#How to add intervals to which the root lies in this code?So that intervals a and b can be entered

```
     from sympy import *
        equation = input('Your equation > ')
        eqn= sympify(input('Eqn'))
        f=lambda x:eqn.subs({'x':x})
        #err - небольшое плавающее число, которое говорит o точности
        def bisection(low, high, err):
            mid = (high+low)/2   
            while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
                print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)

                if f(mid) == 0:
                    return mid #The midpoint is the x-intercept/root.
                elif f(mid) > 0:
                    high = mid
                elif f(mid) < 0:
                    low = mid
                mid = (high + low)/2
            return mid
        print (bisection(0, 100, 0.001))
```

Sorry, I'm confused. And the top of the input function will look like thi
? Then an error comes out, I don’t quite understand how to insert the function and interval imput in such a code и интервала

```
    from sympy import *
        f = input("Your equation > ")
eqn=sympify(equation)
        a = eval (input("а="))
        b = eval (input("b="))
            def bisection(low, high, err):
                mid = (high+low)/2   
                while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
                    print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)
```

Comment: Please clarify more your question. it doesn't seem to be any ```a``` or  ```b``` variables in your code, probably you could explicitly add them. Thanks!

Comment: I want to rewrite the program, but I don’t understand how. I want to be able to write not only a function, but also the interval where this function is located. I wanted to designate the interval a and b. And so, if you drive into the program, the meaning is this: Is there a given function on the intervals a and b

Comment: The question is, how to add intervals?
I will be grateful for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this function works like an approximation to find the root of a function. Under my understanding, you want to also return the values were the root is enclosed between an interval a,b.

Please try this modification:

```py
from sympy import *


def bisection(low, high, err):
    mid = (high+low)/2   
    while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
        print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)

        if f(mid) == 0:
            return mid, high, low # Change [1]. Added high and low here
        elif f(mid) > 0:
            high = mid
        elif f(mid) < 0:
            low = mid
        mid = (high + low)/2

    return mid, high, low # Change [2]. Added high and low here

root, a, b = bisection(0,100,0.001) # Change [3]
print("f Root{root}, Interval ({a},{b})") # Change [4]
```

Explanation:

[1] This change adds the variables `high` and `low` to the `return` statement, so they can be obtained when the `bisection` function is called.

[2] This change adds the variables `high` and `low` to the `return` statement, so they can be obtained when the `bisection` function is called.

[3] Evaluates the variable `root`, `a`, and `b` according to the results given by the `bisection` function.

[4] Prints the results with the format, all the variables appear inside brackets `{}`, everything outside the brackets is text. This type of formatting was introduced in Python 3.6, so if you are using an older version of python you could try this:

- < Python 3.6

```py
print("Root {} ({},{})".format(root,a,b))
print("Root %s (%s, %s)"%(root,a,b))
```

- Python 2.X

```py
print("Root %s (%s, %s)"%(root,a,b))
```

**Edit**

To add user input, lets say `a` and `b` you can use the `input()` method, like this:

```py
from sympy import *

# User Input
a = int(input("Please input a"))
b = int(input("Please input b"))

def bisection(low, high, err):
    mid = (high+low)/2   
    while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
        print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)

        if f(mid) == 0:
            return mid
        elif f(mid) > 0:
            high = mid
        elif f(mid) < 0:
            low = mid
        mid = (high + low)/2

    return mid

root = bisection(a,b,0.001) # Change [3]
print("Root {} ({},{})".format(root,a,b))
```

**Edit 2**

```py
from sympy import *

# Equation inputs
f = input("Your equation > ")
eqn=sympify(equation)

# Intervals
a = eval (input("а="))
b = eval (input("b="))

# Function Change [5]
def bisection(low, high, err, f):
    mid = (high+low)/2   
    while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
        print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)

        if f(mid) == 0:
            return mid
        elif f(mid) > 0:
            high = mid
        elif f(mid) < 0:
            low = mid
        mid = (high + low)/2

    return mid

# Calling the functions with the Input parameters
# In this part you insert the parameters given at the inputs
root = bisection(a,b,err,f) # Change [6]
print("Root {} ({},{})".format(root,a,b))
```

**Explanation**

[5] In this part you are adding the parameter `f` (your mathematical equation) to the arguments of the function `bisection`

[6] Since we added a parameter in [5] you have to modify the call of your function `bisection` to include `f`.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have more questions. :D

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. And the top of the input function will look like thi ?

Comment: Which part is confusing for you?

Comment: I thought you wanted to know the values of the interval where the root lies

Comment: No, I wanted to enter the interval myself, through "input" a and b, but I don’t understand how to rewrite without lambda

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Please check how I edited my code

Comment: Oh no.I needed so that in the program I could write the function itself and the intervals. Lambda did not let me write these intervals. I don’t know how to change the upper part of the codes for me, so that I can write the function f (x) = (here is an example of the function), and then write the interval a and b

Comment: Please take a look to the new edit, I think I understand now your problem